# I need to split a text column in Access that stores dates in MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY format to remove the day format

Tags: date, ms-access, delimiter, ms-access-2013

I have a program that writes dates as text in a column called Expression. Is there a way to write a query that will remove the day of the month? I need it to be something that I can share with multiple people to use in multiple databases. Examples of the format of the values stored are 6/2021, 06/2021, and 06/01/2021.

Comment: Why is date format inconsistent? Can you modify program?

Comment: I cannot modify the program. It just writes it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IIf` in the query to compare the length of the data, and pad/split as required. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    Expression, 
    IIf(Len([Expression])=6,"0" & [Expression],IIf(Len([Expression])=7,[Expression],IIf(Len([expression])=10,Left(Expression,2) & "/" & right(expression,4)))) AS OutputData
FROM tblFormatDate;
```

You may need to add a few more `IIf`s, and also a final false return statement. If it starts to get messy with the data, then you may want to look at creating a custom VBA function that makes the process flow easier to understand.

Regards,

Comment: Seems there is only a day part if string is longer than 7 (assuming year is always 4 digits). That could shorten the IIf() expression. Left() only works if month is always 2 characters. Could use Val() instead.

Comment: True, but we don't know the format of all of the data. Personally, I'd use a VBA function that uses `Split`, counts the elements, and then rejoins as required with the correct seperator.

Comment: I just copy and pasted that code into a query, changed the table and it worked. Thank you.